# Express: BasicAuth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers

I'm trying to do some basic authorisation to my the endpoints in an express app using express-basic-auth, but it keeps giving me a 401 unauthorised. I think the headers I'm sending in Post man are incorrect:

Middleware:

```
app.use(basicAuth({
  users: {'admin': 'supersecret'},
  unauthorizedResponse: 'You are not authorized.'
}));
```

Postman GET request headers:

```
Authorization:admin:supersecret
```

How can I get authorised based on the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your authorization header should look like this: `Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=`

The last part is the result of encoding *admin:supersecret*. I just found [this tool](https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/) to generate basic authentication headers, however, Postman can generate the headers itself. Just click on the Authorization option next to Headers and choose Basic Auth.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't realise it had to be encoded.